# How many transactions can Corda save in its h2 database?

Tags: corda

We need to save about 10 millions transactions (each transaction will save one HASH of a electronic contract) per day and keep them for 3 years at least.

Because Corda can only support h2 database currently, we want to know if Corda can not support saving so many tranactions due to the limit of the database or somethig else?

Answer (score 0):

The open source version of Corda was originally coded against the h2 database. We have had community contributions which enable Corda to run against postgres - although please be aware that this is a contribution so we run all of our testing against h2 and so we may not immediately pick up issues when running against the postgres database platform.

However, "R3 Corda" will support a variety of fully pluggable databases. If you intend to use Corda in a production environment, then I would recommend you use this version for deployment. Any code written against O/S Corda (or running on an O/S Corda node) will be fully compatible with the R3 Corda platform.

Comment: What about the original question if corda allows to save so many transactions? (Say we define "allow" by "can ... in reasonable time with reasonable DB space")